# CSS styles using html direction for RTL support in Polymer 1.0

Tags: css, polymer

In a localized Polymer 1.0 app, I set the top level element dir to "rtl":

```
<html dir="rtl">
  ...
</html>
```

In a custom element, I'd like to change the position based on the directionality, so i'd like a CSS rule like

```
<style>
  html[dir="rtl"] #SomeSubElement { .... }
</style>
```

However, by doing this, Polymer renames the rule to something like

```
html[dir="rtl"].my-custom-element #SomeSubElement.my-custom-element { ... }
```

This prevents the CSS rule from every applying.  Is there a way to avoid this scoping for some portion of the CSS rule, namely the html[dir="rtl"] portion which should apply globally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered the right solution:

```
:host-context(html[dir="rtl"]) { 
   ...
 }
```

This is covered in more detail in [this guide on shadow DOM in Polymer](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/).